# why this text data was not getting print through a printer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, printdocument

when i am trying do printdocument1.print(); system was showing a small model pop up as the file name and system getting keep silent with out throwing any error any thing 
[image]

here is my c# code behind code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;

 namespace csvform
{
public partial class Form3 : Form
{

      private PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
    private string stringToPrint;
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        printDocument1.PrintPage +=
           new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);

    }


     private void ReadFile()
   {
       string docName = "testPage.txt";
       string docPath = @"c:\";
       printDocument1.DocumentName  = docName;
       using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(docPath +
       docName, FileMode.Open))
       using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
       {
           stringToPrint = reader.ReadToEnd();
       }
   }

   private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender,
    PrintPageEventArgs e)
   {
       int charactersOnPage = 0;
       int linesPerPage = 0;
       Font nf = new Font(new FontFamily("Arial"), 10,
       System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
       // Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters
       // of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.
       e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint,nf,
           e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
           out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

       // Draws the string within the bounds of the page
       e.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint,nf, Brushes.Black,
           e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

       // Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
       stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage);

       // Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
       e.HasMorePages = (stringToPrint.Length > 0);
   }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT *           FROM Win32_Printer");
        string printerName = "";
        foreach (ManagementObject printer in searcher.Get())
        {
            printerName = printer["Name"].ToString().ToLower();
            if (printerName.Equals(@"\\chenraqdc2.raqmiyat.local\hp color laserjet cp1510"))
            {                                            
                   // printDocument1.Print();
                    try
                    {
                        // Assumes the default printer.
                        ReadFile();
                        printDocument1.Print();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while printing", ex.ToString());
                    }                      

            }
        }       
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You can't control what the printer driver does once you handed the print job to it.

Comment: @oded : donmine it was not getting print ! i have edited my question now

Comment: IF I SET LIKE THIS IN MY CODE BEHIND MEANS IT WAS SHOWING A PRINTER SETTING DIALOG BOX IF I SELECT APPROPRIATE PRINTER MEANS THEN PRINT WAS HAPPENING BUT MY REQUIREMENT AUTOMATICALLY IT SHOULD DETECT PRINT DEFUALTLY IT SHOULD AND PRINT MUST BE HAPPENING FOR THAT HOW TO AVOID NOT TO COME PRINTER DIALOG BOX CAN ANY ONE PLEASE                              if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                            {
                                printDocument1.PrintController = printcontrol;
                                printDocument1.Print();
                            }

Comment: Your caps-lock seems to be broken. Please do not post ALL CAPS. It is considered rude.

Comment: I will repeat - the dialog comes from the driver - you can't control that.#

Comment: thanks for replying .. any way i got an answer http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Set-default-printer-using-CNET-VS-2008-979.php

Answer (score 1):

[For historical purposes](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Set-default-printer-using-CNET-VS-2008-979.php):

```
// namespace declaration
using System.Management;

// code sample for setting default printer

ManagementObjectCollection objManagementColl;
// class used to invoke the query for specified management collection
ManagementObjectSearcher objManagementSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

// invokes the specified query and returns the resulting collection
objManagementColl = objManagementSearch.Get();

foreach(ManagementObject objManage in objManagementColl)
    {
       if (objManage["Name"].ToString() == "RequiredPrinterName")  // compares the name of printers
          {
             objManage.InvokeMethod("SetDefaultPrinter", null); // invoke [SetDefaultPrinter] method 
             break;
           }
      }
```